# MySQL SELECT + add a character after value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to add a character after a value. For example:

```
SELECT brand FROM `autoinfo` WHERE 1
```

result:

```
Audi  
Ford  
...
```

I need to that result:

```
Audi w  
Ford w  
...
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you need to concatenate a symbol after the `brand`, then use the [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
SELECT concat(brand, ' w') as brand
FROM `autoinfo` 
WHERE 1;
```